# Problems with using the TP-Link TL-WN881ND

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, pci

As you can see in the title, I am having trouble, getting the "TP-Link TL-WN881ND" PCIe Card to work.

I am running at Ubuntu 16.04 and having weird problems with this Card.
I know, that this Card uses the ath9k driver, which is installed and it appears to be correct, given that `sudo lspci -vnn` spits out:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002e] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:30a4]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at feaf0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [60] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-15-17-ff-ff-24-14-12
Capabilities: [170] Power Budgeting <?>
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ndiswrapper
```

However I cannot connect to any WiFi-Network.

My troubleshooting so far:

- In the Network-Settings it shows a wireless section and sometimes even some networks. However, I can't connect to any of them.
- If I plug in my "old" wireless USB-Adapter I can connect to my WiFi. The network then show's up in the Wireless section of, what appears to be the new PCIe-Card, until I try to connect to it. It then magically disappears..
- If i boot up in Windows, it is working just fine, given that I installed the driver.
- I then downloaded and installed the official driver using ndisgtk, but it did not work..

The reason I am posting this here, is that everything seems to be correct, it just doesn't work.

Do you had any similar problems, or an idea how to fix it?

Thanks very much in advance!

(**edit1**):

I removed the ndiswrapper. At this moment it worked, however, after a reboot it didn't anymore. The new output from `sudo lspci -vnn` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002e] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:30a4]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
Memory at feaf0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: ndiswrapper
```

Comment: The problem is that you installed `ndiswrapper`. That was a bad idea. Remove it.

Comment: You have to be kidding me ... It worked ... But what the heck? I mean, it didn't work before.. The ndiswrapper was the last thing i tried, alsmost half an hour into the troubleshooting... Btw. sry for my bad english, it is only my second language

Comment: The more interresting thing is: now it works, but lspci -vnn still gives the same output, including "Kernel modules: ndiswrapper".

Comment: That means you did not remove it completely.

Comment: Alright, after reboot, id does not work anymore